# Gerrit Replication is always Rescheduling

Tags: replication, gerrit

```
There are thousands of this log:

[2021-08-18 20:21:39,663] Rescheduling replication to git://xxx  to avoid collision with the in-flight push [6e810ffc]. [CONTEXT PLUGIN="replication" RECEIVE_ID="xxxx" project="xxx" pushOneId="2d04c11f" ]
[2021-08-18 20:21:42,663] Rescheduling replication to git://xxx  to avoid collision with the in-flight push [6e810ffc]. [CONTEXT PLUGIN="replication" RECEIVE_ID="xxxx" project="xxx" pushOneId="2d04c11f" ]
```

And  the  replication work seems never finish ...

My gerrit version is 3.2.3.

How can I fix this problem? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix action is one of two

1.wait the conflict task to finish

2.cd into the repo folder,such as project.git and run 'git push --mirror ssh://user@RemoteHost:project.git'.The Gerrit Rescheduled task will disappear soon.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for rescheduling is to avoid a collision with an in-flight push to the same URI as you can see from the logs. The replication is re-scheduled according to your configuration trying to avoid it.

You should understand why you have so many concurrent replications to the same URI creating the collisions.

Comment: Agree and thanks for your advise.Gerrit source code shows there are a few reasons of Re-Schedule. Such as push in-flight , refs not updated, and so on? Trying to find out.